# Switching site from a query doesn't work right now

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

From any query (i.e. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag), if you run it, you get the array of other site icons to run the same query on.

If you check the URLs, on each one the query id is reset back to zero (i.e. https://data.stackexchange.com/android%20enthusiasts/query/0/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag).

Comment: Confirmed. But, what does it matter when the site icons are lined up sensibly, now?  (^_^)

Answer (score 6):

Fixed, sorry it was a major restructure. Also ... look the icons are in a coherent order.

Which reminds me ... all I need is 35 more upvotes for my gold bug badge. Let's make it happen!

Comment: OK, so you make the bugs first, then I'll report them, is that the plan? :)

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.RevisionExecutions' with unique index 'idxUniqueExecutions'. The duplicate key value is (0, 1, 785). The statement has been terminated." When I try to run that query. Not logged in.

Comment: works for me :) ... I really need some feedback on the new "revision" and workflow on data explorer

Comment: @Scrooge good point, I should not log revision executions for anon

Comment: I can report a separate bug if you want :)

Comment: @Scrooge already fixed and deployed